# get currently displayed fragments in list like UI

Tags: android, android-fragments

I am adding fragments in activities UI along with tags. So it looks list like UI which is scrollable. And in activities onResume I want to get only fragments which are displayed on screen.

So e.g. There are 10 fragments in list like UI, and user can see only 5 of them on Ui and can see remaining when he scrolls.

I want those first 5 visible fragments. Here is ma code.

```
    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();

    Fragment listitemFragment = getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag(TAG);
    if(listitemFragment != null && listitemFragment.isVisible()) {
      //my code
    }
}
```

isVisible() is returning true to all 10 fragments even though user is able to see only 5 on screen. Please help me. Is it right way of doing this? is there any different way? Or am I doing something wrong?

Thanks in advance